# Can I do a django get latest where ==

Tags: python, django

I already have a function to get latest by date
`foo.objects.latest('date_added').itemName`
I want to know if it is possible some something similar but with an added `where`
like if I have type a, b or c 
I want to get the latest by `date_added` where it is type c for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo.objects.filter(type='c').latest('date_added')
```